# SBT assembly falis

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am running a spark job through intellij. Job executes and gives me output. i need to take this job as jar file to server and run, but when i try to do            `sbt assembly` it throws below error:

```
 [error] Not a valid command: assembly
 [error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
 [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
 [error] Not a valid key: assembly
 [error] assembly
```

my sbt version is `0.13.8`

below is my build.sbt file:

```
import sbt._, Keys._
name := "mobilewalla"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0")
```

i added a file assembly.sbt under project dir. it contains:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

what am i missing here

Comment: Did you reload after installing sbt assembly?

Comment: Yes i did it. is by Build.sbt file correct? should i need to add anything to it?

Comment: `sbt package` creates your JAR file for spark submit...  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications

Comment: `sbt package` creates a jar of code file. i need a standalone jar which has to be done by sbt assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines in your build.sbt

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.SparkMain")
resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"
assemblyJarName in assembly := "streaming-api.jar"
```

and include these lines in your plugins.sbt file

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.7.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

Comment: can you please let me know why do we need `sbt-revolver` setting in plugins file

Comment: This is a very useful plugin that can run your project in a forked JVM and reload it on a change.

Answer (score 0):

To assemble the multiple jars to one u need add below plugin in plugins.sbt under project directory.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

If u need to customize the assembled jar to trigger specific MainClass take example assembly.sbt

```
import sbtassembly.Plugin.AssemblyKeys._

Project.inConfig(Compile)(baseAssemblySettings)

mainClass in (Compile, assembly) := Some("<main application name  with package path>")

jarName in (Compile, assembly) := s"${name.value}-${version.value}-dist.jar"
//below is merge strategy to make what all file need to exclude or include
mergeStrategy in (Compile, assembly) <<= (mergeStrategy in (Compile, assembly)) {
  (old) => {
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" =>MergeStrategy.first
    case "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think these lines are necessary for an Apache spark project

Comment: i added assembly.sbt file with ref : [sbt assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) as my sbt version is 0.13.8

Comment: You should still try using plugins.sbt . If the doc were perfect in, you wouldn't be asking a question on SO in the first place :)

Comment: @toofrellik plugin should be in plugins.sbt,its not becoz u have assembly.sbt .sbt won't recognize assembly.You should have add sbt-assembly  in plugins.sbt

Comment: @cricket_007 his requirement is to pack all the jars into one and make standalone.If u need to customize ,u need those lines for assembled jar to pick main App